# Attempt at running a condition based on file type using strpos

Tags: php, file, file-upload, strpos

I am in the process of creating a condition. The condition is to check if any of the files are not basic image files (png, jpg, etc -- files shown in the condition) right away (in the if). If this is the case then the file_put_contents should run. If there are only basic image files being uploaded then the else should run.

As of now, the else never runs. For example, if I upload one file that is a .png the else statement should run.

When someone adds a file, I check the file type with `$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();` and then implode it to a list. This 100% works.

Here is an example of what I am wanting to happen:

If someone uploads two files -  a .png and .stp, then the if should run. I am wanting the else to run only if the files being uploaded are the basic image files. Is there a better way to do this?

Then I am using the strpos function to check each type of image file I specified.

```
if (strpos($fileTypeString,$pdf) || strpos($fileTypeString,$jpg) || strpos($fileTypeString,$jpeg) || strpos($fileTypeString,$png) || strpos($fileTypeString,$gif) === false) {
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
$fileTypeString = implode( ", ", $uploadedFileTypes );
$pdf = "pdf";
$jpg = "jpg";
$jpeg = "jpeg";
$png = "png";
$gif = "gif";
file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true), FILE_APPEND);

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) { //empty string
            if ($file['error'][$key] != 4) {
                if (strpos($fileTypeString,$pdf) || strpos($fileTypeString,$jpg) || strpos($fileTypeString,$jpeg) || strpos($fileTypeString,$png) || strpos($fileTypeString,$gif) === false) {
                    file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);
                } else {
                    $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
                    foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                        //print_r($template);
                        $out .= "<li><a href='/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
                    }
                    $out .= '</ul>';
                    $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
                }
            } else { //error code IS #4
                //echo "error code is 4";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "name is empty!";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit, New code with different approach:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
$fileTypeString = implode( ", ", $uploadedFileTypes);
$imageTypes = ["pdf","jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"];
$nonImgFiles = false;
$imgFiles = false;

if (!in_array($uploadedFileTypes, $imageTypes)) {
    $nonImgFiles = true;
}

if (in_array($uploadedFileTypes, $imageTypes)) {
    $imgFiles = true;
}

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) { //empty string
            if ($file['error'][$key] != 4) {        
                if ($nonImgFiles == true) {
                    file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);
                } else {
                    }
```

Comment: You should have `=== false` on all of the `strpos()`'s - just doing it on the last one isn't the same thing.

Comment: @NigelRen Good catch. However, I just corrected and tried again. The else is still not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `=== false` to all the conditionals and change the operator to `&&`, like:

```
if (
    strpos($fileTypeString,$pdf) === false && 
    strpos($fileTypeString,$jpg) === false && 
    strpos($fileTypeString,$jpeg) === false && 
    strpos($fileTypeString,$png) === false && 
    strpos($fileTypeString,$gif) === false
) {
    //do something    
} else {
   //do something
}
```

But it seems that you can achieve that using less code in that `if` doing:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true), FILE_APPEND);

$extensions = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']; //an array with your extensions
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) { //empty string
            if ($file['error'][$key] != 4) {
                $fileData = pathinfo($file['name']); //explod file path to array
                if (!in_array($fileData['extension'], $extensions)) { //if file extension not in your $extensions array
                    file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);
                } else {
                    $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
                    foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                        //print_r($template);
                        $out .= "<li><a href='/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
                    }
                    $out .= '</ul>';
                    $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
                }
            } else { //error code IS #4
                //echo "error code is 4";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "name is empty!";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I reread your question. I believe you will need to remove the **file extension** checking outside the loop. Something like this would work:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();

file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true), FILE_APPEND);

//your per-file validation loop can go here

$extensions = 'pdf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];

//fill $differentExtensions with all $uploadedFileTypes elements that 
//does not exist inside $extensions
$differentExtensions = array_diff($uploadedFileTypes, $extensions);
if (count($differentExtensions) > 0) {
    file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);  
} else {
    $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
    foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
        //print_r($template);
        $out .= "<li><a href='/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
    $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
}

//your per-file validation loop can go here
```

The loop you are using to validate errors would be a separate code block. You could place it before or after the **file extension** checking, depending on what you need (I mentioned suggested places as comments in the code above):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            //echo "name is empty!";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
        }
        if ($file['error'][$key] == 4) {
            //echo "error code is 4";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `$fileData`? Can't I just use my list that I already created? `$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
  $fileTypeString = implode( ", ", $uploadedFileTypes );`

Comment: It's just a different approach. If you take this one, neither `$uploadedFileTypes` nor `$fileTypeString` will be needed anymore. I edited the code in my answer

Comment: The thing is the image files and other files are going to be uploaded together.  I don't need to check if the image files are empty. I need to check if there are files being uploaded that aren't specified in `$extensions`. Then even if image files are uploaded with other types of files at the same time, the if part still runs.

Comment: Have you tried any my code? The first one is a solution, and the second one is just an improvement, to the bottom line of your question (why the `else` doesn't get executed?) as well as @Nigel Ren answer is. If you tried these approaches and, even with the else being executed, you are not getting the expected result, the problem is not your `if`. If that's the case, you should post a new question

Comment: `why the else doesn't get executed?` is not the bottom line of my question. Yes, I have tried your solution and it doesn't work like I require. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I edited my question with the new code. I went about this in a new direction. However, it still doesn't work. This could just be something I am missing. Do you think this will work or ideas why it isn't working? Only the if part runs.

Comment: This works perfectly! Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough or didn't understand what you were trying to do. I appreciate all of the help and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest an alternative way of checking the file types, rather than mangling strings and checking different variables, have an array of the types you want to capture and then check if the ones uploaded match any of them (using `array_intersect()` in this example)...

```
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
$imagesTypes = ["pdf","jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"];
```

would give you the arrays to compare

Then your test would be something like...

```
if ( empty(array_intersect($uploadedFileTypes, $imagesTypes)) ) {
```

If you want to ensure what types are loaded, you can change this round so that you start with...

```
$imagesTypes = ["png","stp"];
```

and then the check would be if there are any differences between the types and the extensions you are expecting...

```
if ( !empty(array_diff($uploadedFileTypes, $imagesTypes)) ) {
```

Comment: I've updated it with the alternative of matching the specific extensions you are after.

Comment: The thing is I am not after a specific extension other than images. The reason for doing this: When someone just uploads image files, I will be making a list of urls in an email that is sent to them. However, when someone uploads any type of non-image file, I will then zip all of the files as an attachment.

Comment: There may be 50 or more different file types being uploaded. The ones I declared are the only ones I need to check for. If 3 files are uploaded: `[.png, .stp, .par]` then the if needs to run. Even though an image file is included, there are other types of non image files. Does this make sense?

Comment: This code isn't specific to image files or any types of files, all this code does is to match the extension of a file.  How you use it is flexible - use `count(array_intersect($uploadedFileTypes, $imagesTypes))` to see how many files in the list match, use `array_unique($uploadedFileTypes)` to make sure it only checks at least one of each is loaded.

Comment: Then wouldn't this make more sense or is it possible? `if ( array_intersect($uploadedFileTypes, !$imagesTypes)) )`  I am wanting to check against whether the files are the image files.

Comment: `!$imagesTypes` isn't possible.  You would have to say the result of `array_intersect()` returns no entries (I think) to say that none of the files are images.

Comment: How would that be written up then?

Comment: That was the first code example I gave `if ( empty(array_intersect($uploadedFileTypes, $imagesTypes)) ) {`

Comment: Something is still off. Now only the else runs. I don't need to check if the image files are empty. I need to check if there are files being uploaded that aren't specified in `$imagesTypes`.

Comment: I edited my question with the new code. I went about this in a new direction. However, it still doesn't work. This could just be something I am missing. Do you think this will work or ideas why it isn't working? Only the if part runs.